# Python 3: UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope

The following code gives the error `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Var1' referenced before assignment`:

```
Var1 = 1
Var2 = 0
def function(): 
    if Var2 == 0 and Var1 > 0:
        print("Result 1")
    elif Var2 == 1 and Var1 > 0:
        print("Result 2")
    elif Var1 < 1:
        print("Result 3")
    Var1 -= 1
function()
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Notice that it will work if you use `dic = {'Var1':1, 'Var2':0}` and access Var1 and Var2 through the dictionary.

Comment: Beside the point, but `Var1 =- 1` is parsed as `Var1 = -1`, not `Var1 -= 1`

Comment: How comes doesn't give error UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Var2' referenced before assignment? Even when you change if Var2 == 0 and Var1 > 0: to if Var2 == 0:

Comment: @chikitin It doesn't give error for Var2 because in your function you have no where assigned any value to Var2, because of which it considers the global value of Var2 by default. But since, you have mentioned Var1=- 1 which python interprets as Var1 = -1, it considers that Var1 is assigned a local value and hence Var1 becomes a local & a global variable, which python considers separate.  Since this  assignment of Var1 comes after using Var1 in the same function, we get this reference before assignment error. Hope this gives some clarity

Comment: @chikitin Just in case, if you want to pop error for Var2 as well just to check and clarify your doubt, just assign some value to Var2 as well below Var1=-1 statement and then you'll get error for Var2 as well.

Comment: I have same problem, i used dictionary `dic = {'Var1':1, 'Var2':0}`

Comment: keep outside variable  initialization as it is and inside function first define global Var1,Var2

reference link : https://www.techgeekbuzz.com/python-local-variable-referenced-before-assignment-solution/

Comment: As @Sugandha pointed out, Var1 and Var2 were used/referenced as global variables until the last assignment statement of Var1 = -1, where it tried to declare a local variable Var1 and found that it has already been referenced as a global variable, hence a conflict resulted. It is essentially like this code: `v = 1; def f(): v = v - 1; f()` To fix it, just use a pass-in `v = 1; def f(v): v = v - 1; f(v)`

Comment: A good explanation can be found here: [global-local-and-nonlocal-variables-in-python](https://towardsdatascience.com/global-local-and-nonlocal-variables-in-python-6b11c20d73b0)

Answer (score 105, accepted):

You can fix this by passing parameters rather than relying on Globals

```
def function(Var1, Var2): 
    if Var2 == 0 and Var1 > 0:
        print("Result One")
    elif Var2 == 1 and Var1 > 0:
        print("Result Two")
    elif Var1 < 1:
        print("Result Three")
    return Var1 -= 1
function(1, 1)
```

Comment: I think this simple sample code just shows the issue. The specific solution is not clear enough for such a case.

Comment: The last line should be `Var1 -= 1` instead of `Var1 - 1`

Answer (score 736):

This is because, even though `Var1` exists, you're also using an assignment statement on the name `Var1` inside of the function (`Var1 -= 1` at the bottom line). Naturally, this creates a variable inside the function's scope called `Var1` (truthfully, a `-=` or `+=` will only update (reassign) an existing variable, but for reasons unknown (likely consistency in this context), Python treats it as an assignment). The Python interpreter sees this at module load time and decides (correctly so) that the global scope's `Var1` should not be used inside the local scope, which leads to a problem when you try to reference the variable before it is locally assigned.

Using global variables, outside of necessity, is usually frowned upon by Python developers, because it leads to confusing and problematic code. However, if you'd like to use them to accomplish what your code is implying, you can simply add, **inside the top of your function**:

```
global Var1, Var2
```

This will tell Python that you **do not** intend to define a `Var1` or `Var2` variable inside the function's local scope. The Python interpreter sees this at module load time and decides (correctly so) to look up any references to the aforementioned variables in the global scope.

#### Some Resources

- the Python website has a [great explanation](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value) for this common issue.
- Python 3 offers a related [`nonlocal`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#nonlocal) statement - check that out as well.

Comment: @user7344209 Indeed. Answers should ideally explain what's happening in the actual example shown, and how to fix that, rather than suggesting a whole different approach.

Comment: "Naturally", it does not seem natural to me.

Comment: @dumbledad I only mean “naturally” in the sense that `+=` is an assignment operator (`iadd`, which stands for “in-place add”)

Comment: Nicely explained with a workable solution

Comment: What is the process that is to blame for this kind of phenomenon? I'd like to look into if other languages do something similar but I'm not sure what to google.

Comment: @orokusaki: `__iadd__` is not used with int objects as they are immutable. Python falls back on using `__add__` in this case

Answer (score 170):

If you set the value of a variable inside the function, python understands it as creating a local variable with that name. This local variable masks the global variable.

In your case, `Var1` is considered as a local variable, and it's used before being set, thus the error.

To solve this problem, you can explicitly say it's a global by putting `global Var1` in you function.

```
Var1 = 1
Var2 = 0
def function():
    global Var1
    if Var2 == 0 and Var1 > 0:
        print("Result One")
    elif Var2 == 1 and Var1 > 0:
        print("Result Two")
    elif Var1 < 1:
        print("Result Three")
    Var1 =- 1
function()
```

Answer (score 14):

I don't like this behavior, but this is how Python works. The question has already been answered by others, but for completeness, let me point out that Python 2 has more such quirks.

```
def f(x):
    return x

def main():
    print f(3)
    if (True):
        print [f for f in [1, 2, 3]]

main()
```

Python 2.7.6 returns an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "weird.py", line 9, in <module>
    main()
  File "weird.py", line 5, in main
    print f(3)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'f' referenced before assignment
```

Python sees the `f` is used as a local variable in `[f for f in [1, 2, 3]]`, and decides that it is also a local variable in `f(3)`. You could add a `global f` statement:

```
def f(x):
    return x

def main():
    global f
    print f(3)
    if (True):
        print [f for f in [1, 2, 3]]

main()
```

It does work; however, *f becomes 3 at the end...* That is, `print [f for f in [1, 2, 3]]` now changes the global variable `f` to `3`, so it is not a function any more.

Fortunately, it works fine in Python3 after adding the parentheses to `print`.

Answer (score 6):

Why not simply return your calculated value and let the caller modify the global variable. It's not a good idea to manipulate a global variable within a function, as below:

```
Var1 = 1
Var2 = 0

def function(): 
    if Var2 == 0 and Var1 > 0:
        print("Result One")
    elif Var2 == 1 and Var1 > 0:
        print("Result Two")
    elif Var1 < 1:
        print("Result Three")
    return Var1 - 1

Var1 = function()
```

or even make local copies of the global variables and work with them and return the results which the caller can then assign appropriately

```
def function():
v1, v2 = Var1, Var2
# calculate using the local variables v1 & v2
return v1 - 1

Var1 = function()
```