# how to access global variable and change its value at local level in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, global-variables

Here i have a code of python. In this code i define two function and at top one variable a i have created. but when i try to call a in local function with assigning statement below it generate error that local variable not initialized. if i didn't assign it value than it access value of successfully.

```
 a=5
 def local():
     print("inside local Function before changing %d"%a)
     a=3
     print("Insie local Function after changing %d"%a)
 local()
 print("outside local Function after changing %d"%a)
 def global_ars():
     global a
     a=6
     print("Inside Global Function %d"%a)
global_ars()
print("outside Global Function %d"%a)
```

i want to know how can i access to global value and can assign new value but only at local level not on global level.

Comment: If you google python 3 + the error message from your code the top entry (for me) is http://stackoverflow.com/q/10851906/1144523

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to start with the global value, but have assignments only affect a local copy, the solution is to just make another variable:

```
def f():
    local_a = a
    # Now use local_a instead of a.
```

If you want assignments inside the function to affect the global variable, use `global`, like you're already doing.

Answer (score 0):

Simply get the value from the global scope and don't modify the global variable:

```
a = 0
def global_fn():
    global a
    local_a = a
    print("local original %d"%local_a)
    local_a = 10
    print("local modified %d"%local_a)
 global_fn()
 print("global unmodified %d"%a)
```