# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Line7' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

### I get this error in my python programme:

```
Line = (str(Line7) + (" ") + str(Line2))
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Line7' referenced before assignment
```

### For this part of the code:

```
Line7 = ("Y Y Y B B B G G G")
Line2 = ("O O O")
def Rotation_Top_Right():
    Line = (str(Line7) + (" ") + str(Line2))
    print(Line)
    Line_List = []
    for i in range(12):
        i -= 3
        Line_List.append(Line.split(" ")[i])
    for i in range(9):
        Line7 = Line_List[i]
    for i in range(3):
        i -= 3
        Line2 = Line_List[i]
Rotation_Top_Right()
```

Tar in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the code is organized that way? Aren't you calling the function before the `Line7` assignment?

Comment: No, the function is being called after.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python 3: UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851906/python-3-unboundlocalerror-local-variable-referenced-before-assignment)

Answer (score 0):

You need to either declare them inside or pass them to the function:

```
def Rotation_Top_Right(): # inside function
    Line7 = ("Y Y Y B B B G G G")
    Line2 = ("O O O")

def Rotation_Top_Right(Line7,Line2): # use as parameters and pass
```

You can use `global` also but I would recommend that you not.

You can also rename the variables in your function that are shadowing the variables from the  global namespace as you are actually reassigning and not updating the values:

```
Line7 = ("Y Y Y B B B G G G")
Line2 = ("O O O")
def Rotation_Top_Right():
    Line = (str(Line7) + (" ") + str(Line2))
    Line_List = []
    for i in range(12):
        i -= 3
        Line_List.append(Line.split(" ")[i])
    for i in range(9):
        Line_7 = Line_List[i] # change to Line_7 
    for i in range(3):
        i -= 3
        Line_2= Line_List[i] # change to Line_2
```

I would still favour passing in the variables.

Comment: @PabloAntonio, no it would not, why don't you try it

Comment: I was trying it in the interpreter, and it was working, but when I copied everything to a file, the error appeared.