# 'str' object has no attribute 'len'

Tags: python, django, loops, scope

Ive got a method that use to work by checking the first three letters/numbers and making sure they are the same before it continues like so

```
def combineProcess(request):
    carID1 = request.POST['carID1']
    carID2 = request.POST['carID2']
    for x in range (0,3):
        a += carID1.length(x)
        b += carID2.length(x)
    if a.equals(b):
        //do something
```

before it use to work now it stopped and i get this error.

```
Exception Type: UnboundLocalError
Exception Value:    

local variable 'a' referenced before assignment
```

which i never use to get a few weeks ago didnt change anything so i made a and b global.

```
def combineProcess(request):
    carID1 = request.POST['carID1']
    carID2 = request.POST['carID2']
    global a,b
    for x in range (0,3):
        a += carID1.length(x)
        b += carID2.length(x)
    if a.equals(b):
        //do something
```

Now I am getting this error.

```
Exception Type: NameError
Exception Value:    

name 'a' is not defined
```

Then i removed the global line and just put this

```
a = "P"
```

and got the following error

```
str object has no attribute length() or len()
```

which now has me puzzled how has this code stop working and why cant it recognize that a string object has a len() method. mainly I am lost how my code went from working to not working over a two weeks off.

Comment: Please fix your indentation. It's impossible for us to know what's in the functions. Use 4 spaces to get a code block and another 4 spaces to show the indentation of the function.

Comment: Are you sure you're writing Python here, rather than something else like Java? Quite apart from the issue with `.length()`, strings don't have an `.equals` method in Python either.

Comment: i think that could be the problem cause i code daily with two langauges python and c# so i might be just confusing the two

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Python String len() Method

**Syntax**

Following is the syntax for len() method −

```
len( str )
```

**Example**

```
str = "this is string example....wow!!!";
print("Length of the string: ", len(str))
```

When we run above program, it produces following result −

```
Length of the string:  32
```

**Reference**: [Python String len() Method](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_len.htm)

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment

**Explanation**

This is because, even though `a` and `b` exists, you're also using an assignment statement on the name `a` and `b` inside of the function `combineProcess()`. Naturally, this creates a variable inside the function's scope called `a` and `b`.

The Python interpreter sees this at module load time and decides that the global scope's of `a` and `b` should not be used inside the local scope, which leads to a problem when you try to reference the variable before it is locally assigned.

**Example**

```
Var1 = 1
Var2 = 0
def function():
    if Var2 == 0 and Var1 > 0:
        print("Result One")
    Var1 =- 1

function()
```

If you run this program, it gives the following error.

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Var1' referenced before assignment
```

Since, the value of `Var1` is modified, this creates a variable inside the function's scope called `Var1`. As a result error is reported because of the condition check, `Var1 > 0` before the `Var1 =- 1` statement.

But if we modify the code as follows.

```
Var1 = 1
Var2 = 0
def function():
    global Var1
    if Var2 == 0 and Var1 > 0:
        print("Result One")
    Var1 =- 1

function()
```

Then it works fine.

Note that, if we move the statement `Var1 =- 1` before the `if` condition check, then it will not report any error even if you don't use `global Var1` statement. So, the following code works fine.

```
Var1 = 1
Var2 = 0
def function():
    Var1 =- 1
    if Var2 == 0 and Var1 > 0:
        print("Result One")

function()
```

**Reference**: See this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10852003/5352399).

> NameError: name 'a' is not defined

**Explanation**

Probably you are getting this error because in Python, you cannot compare two strings using `equals()` method. There is no such method exists.

**Example**: Comparing two strings

You can use `> , < , <= , <= , == , !=` to compare two strings. Python compares string lexicographically i.e using ASCII value of the characters. For example, to compare two strings for equality, you can do as follows.

```
if string1 == string2:
    // do something
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you've come from a language such as Java where you call functions directly on strings. You *could* do that in Python:

```
>>> A = "Hello"
>>> B = "Hello"
>>> A.__len__()
5

>>> A.__eq__(B)
True
```

However, the proper way of doing it is like so:

```
>>> len(A)
5

>>> A == B
True
```

---

With that being said, I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish with the length function there. You said your code is checking whether the first 3 letters of the 2 strings are the same - you can do that like so:

```
A = "car123"
B = "car456"

print(A[:3] == B[:3]) # -> True
```

This uses Python's slice notation to get the first 3 characters of each string, and compares these slices with each other.

Comment: thansk for the help i dont know why but i got the two confused ( C# and python ) and it was only when you guys helped that it became clear but what i still dont understand was why was the code working like the original way......im puzzled why it just stopped but thanks i will make the necessary changes