# len() function gives an error when i try to use it

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was doing a codewars challenge where you had to find the smallest wird on a string and i decided to use the len() function but whenever ran the code it gave me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    test.assert_equals(find_short("bitcoin take over the world maybe who knows perhaps"), 3)
  File "/home/codewarrior/solution.py", line 5, in find_short
    if word.len() < l:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'len'
```

here is the defective code, i really can't find what is wrong with it:

```py
def find_short(s):
    foo = s.split()
    l = 100
    for word in foo:
        if word.len() < l:
            l = word.len()
        else:
            continue

    return l # l: shortest word length
```

Comment: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'len'` - what is unclear in this message?

Comment: use `len(word)`

Comment: Before asking a question, make sure to do some of your own research. Searching for the error message you gave leads to this already-answered question: ['str' object has no attribute 'len'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41368066/str-object-has-no-attribute-len).

Answer (score 1):

strings dont have a `len` attribute, you call the `len()` function with the string as an argument.

```
def find_short(s):
    foo = s.split()
    l = 100
    for word in foo:
        if len(word) < l:
            l = len(word)
        else:
            continue

    return l # l: shortest word length
```

Answer (score 1):

`len` is a *function*, not a method.

```
if len(word) < l:
    l = len(word)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, `len` *does* actually have a [method counterpart](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__len__):

```
word.__len__()
```

This is what the `len` standalone function calls internally. If you implement a object and want it to work with `len`, you implement the `__len__` method for it.

It shouldn't be used directly though unless you have a good reason. `len` does some checks on the data retuned by `__len__` to ensure correctness:

```
class L:
    def __len__(self):
        return -4

print(len(L()))

ValueError: __len__() should return >= 0
```

and you'll bypass those checks if you use the "dunder method" directly.