# How do I do global import in python?

Tags: python

I was just getting started with reportlab, when I stumbled upon something. I started with some basic code:

```
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

def generateDoc(docName, title, codefilesFolderPath, docTextFilePath):

    canvas = canvas.Canvas(docName, pagesize=letter) 
    canvas.setLineWidth(.3)
    canvas.setFont('Helvetica', 12)
    canvas.drawString(30,750,'OFFICIAL COMMUNIQUE')
    canvas.save()

generateDoc("temp.pdf","","","")
```

It was giving me following error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'canvas' referenced before assignment
```

I have come to know that global variables are not freely allowed in python as in case of other languages and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10852003/1317018) asks to use `global` keyword. However I am unable to get how I am supposed to do that in above code.

I tried putting `import` at various places, but I am not able to get how do I do this.

Comment: ...Why are you trying to overwrite the `reportlab.pdfgen.canvas` module with a `Canvas` object? I think you just need to choose better names for your variables... (i.e. names that don't clash)

Comment: aah thats what I also thought, but the code is simply copy paste from [here](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/03/08/a-simple-step-by-step-reportlab-tutorial/)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159720/what-is-the-naming-convention-in-python-for-variable-and-function-names

Comment: Well... Now you know that you need to find a better place to copy your code from.

Answer (score 0):

Your local variable `canvas` hides the imported module `canvas`.

You could import `Canvas` directly:

```
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.pdfgen.canvas import Canvas

def generateDoc(docName, title, codefilesFolderPath, docTextFilePath):

    canvas = Canvas(docName, pagesize=letter) 
    canvas.setLineWidth(.3)
    canvas.setFont('Helvetica', 12)
    canvas.drawString(30,750,'OFFICIAL COMMUNIQUE')
    canvas.save()

generateDoc("temp.pdf","","","")
```