# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'checking' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, function, global, local

I have problem which cannot fix. I get the error

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'checking' referenced before assignment

My code

```
    def volume_checker_first_stage(volume1,volume2,withdraw_minimun):
      if volume1>volume2:
       quantity = volume2
       if quantity > withdraw_minimun:
            checking = True
       return quantity, checking
      elif volume2>volume1:
       quantity = volume1
       if quantity > withdraw_minimun:
              checking = True
       return quantity, checking
      else:
       return None,None
```

Comment: `checking` is not defined for the case: `quantity <= withdraw_minimun`. You might want to define `checking = False` in the beginning of your function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 3: UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851906/python-3-unboundlocalerror-local-variable-referenced-before-assignment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the first line of the body of your function, code this:

```
checking = False
```

You have a `return` statement that returns the value of `checking`, but your code doesn't always set it. `Referenced before assignment` means your `return` statement asked for the value of the variable before your code assigned it.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize `checking` to `False` as the first line in your function to avoid this error.