# "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'TimerOnOff' referenced before assignment"

Tags: python

Can someone help me with fixing this problem? When I run this program I get the Error "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'TimerOnOff' referenced before assignment"

```
TimerOnOff = 0
Timer = 7.5
class Timeout():
    def start():
        Timer = 7.5
        if TimerOnOff == 1:
            for T in range(0, 75):
                Timer - 0.1
                time.sleep(0.1)
                print(Timer)
            TimerOnOff = 0

TimerOnOff = 1
Timeout.start()
```

Comment: Look especially at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10852003/8472976

Comment: As a side note, I don't think `Timer - 0.1` does what you want (nothing). Probably wanted `Timer -= 1` or `Timer = Timer - 1`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use global variables like `TimerOnOff` or `Timer` in function, you need do add a statement to specify that you are using global variables in local scope. So you need to add

```
global TimerOnOff
global Timer
```

in your function body. Full implementation would be:

```
import time
TimerOnOff = 0
Timer = 7.5
class Timeout():
    def start():
        global TimerOnOff
        global Timer
        Timer = 7.5
        if TimerOnOff == 1:
            for T in range(0, 75):
                Timer - 0.1
                time.sleep(0.1)
                print(Timer)
            TimerOnOff = 0

TimerOnOff = 1
Timeout.start()
```