# Getting UnboundLocalError error while using string counting

Tags: python, string, count, python-3.7

I got this error `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'total' referenced before assignment` while running the code below.
First sorry for asking this silly question, I know it's very easy one but I don't seemed to understand it somehow, so thought to ask you guys.

```
total = 0
def count(string, letter):
    for x in string:
        if x == letter:
            total +=1
    print(y)
```

as per my knowledge the `total` has been assigned before the function so it should be Global variable and can be used anywhere in the script.
when I used

```
def count(string, letter):
    total = 0
    for x in string:
        if x == letter:
            total +=1
    print(y)
```

when I ran this, using assignment of `total` inside the function it worked fine. But I want to know why I got the error above at first place.
Please explain me. I'm learning it by my own with a pdf and help of you guys.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to declare it global inside your function. Any variable you assign to is assumed local.

Comment: You can fix this by passing parameters rather than relying on Globals

Comment: @nakE copied from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10851939/3890632)

Comment: @khelwood And ?

Comment: And not attributed.

Comment: @khelwood Right, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, "total" variable must be declared/defined inside the `count(string, letter)` function. In Python a function can't access an outer/global variable like a function in JavaScript, except passing an outer variable to that function as an argument like so `count(string, letter, total)`, but previously we need to define the function with theses three parameters instead.

Comment: Thanks, your answer explained me what I wanted to  understand.