# Javascript vs Python indentation

Tags: python, function

I want to make a function work like an on off switch in python. I know how to do it in Javascript, but I don't understand how indenting works with Python, can someone help point me in the right direction?

```
<p id="demo">test</p>
<button onClick="myFunction()">change</button>

<script>
var onoff = 1;

function myFunction() {
    if(onoff == 1){
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "one";
        onoff = 2;
    }
    else if(onoff == 2){
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "two";
        onoff = 1;
    }
}
</script>
```

```
onoff = 1

def test():
  if onoff == 1:
    print("on")
    onoff = 2
  elif onoff == 2:
    print("off")
    onoff = 1


test()
test()
test()
test()
```

Comment: It's not a problem of indentation, it's one of *scope*. Research the error message.

Answer (score 0):

This is about scope as @jonrsharpe commented.

Did you run and notice the error below?

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'onoff' referenced before assignment

There are many solutions. Here is an example.

```
onoff = 1

def test():
  global onoff
  if onoff == 1:
    print("on")
    onoff = 2
  elif onoff == 2:
    print("off")
    onoff = 1


test()
test()
test()
test()
```

see:

- [python - UnboundLocalError on local variable when reassigned after first use - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370357/unboundlocalerror-on-local-variable-when-reassigned-after-first-use)
- [UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment in
  Python.](https://medium.com/@vbsreddy1/unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value-in-python-e34e097547d6)
- [function - Python 3: UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced
  before assignment - Stack
  Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851906/python-3-unboundlocalerror-local-variable-referenced-before-assignment)