# Python error when asking to return a variable (referenced before assignment)

Tags: python, variables

I have the following code but Python keeps saying "*local variable 'a' referenced before assignment*"

```
def inter(X,Y):
    if pertenece(cabeza(X),Y):
        a = lista(cabeza(X),inter(cola(X),Y))
    elif vacia(cola(X)): return a
    else: inter(cola(X),Y)
```

I have no idea why I'm getting this error since I have defined '*a*' before referencing it. Please help.

The functions '*pertenece*', '*cabeza*', '*cola*', '*vacia*' and '*lista*' where all previously defined and have no issue.

Comment: `return a` will only happen if `pertenece(cabeza(X),Y)` is False, but `a` will only be set if `pertenece(cabeza(X),Y)` is True. What do you want `a` to be when `pertenece(cabeza(X),Y)` is False?

Comment: It wouldn't enter elif condition when it has entered if condition.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python 3: UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851906/python-3-unboundlocalerror-local-variable-referenced-before-assignment)

Comment: @Carcigenicate , is there a way to sort of 'bring the value of  'a'? Something like assigning a permanent value for 'a'?

Comment: @RandomUser Set it before the `if`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because you're initializing var a in an if clause, and refrencing it in another if clause, so considering the condition it may or may not be initialized befored it is referenced in if clause. Can you try to initialize a within the function body before your first if clause, to a empty or null value. Maybe that could help.

Answer (score 0):

You have only defined `a` in the first conditional statement. If the code never goes through that condition, then `a` will never be defined. You would have to assign some default value for `a` before the conditional statements in order to prevent the `return` statement from throwing an error at you.