# Why does Python recognize certain variables which are outside of the body function (example with a list) but not others?

Tags: python, function

I'm currently learning Python, and couldn't get my mind around this variable position "paradox" (which exists only to the level of my "beginners knowledge" in Python).

## Example 1

#creating a function which returns the elements of a list called i.

```
def var_i1():

    i = [1,2,3,4]

    for elt in i:

        print(elt)
var_i1()
```

#This successfully prints :

```
1
2
3
4
```

## Example 2

#creating a function which returns the elements of a list called i. i is outside of the body var_i2()

```
i = [1,2,3,4]

def var_i2():

    for elt in i:
        print(elt)

var_i2()
```

#allthough i is outside of the function body (correct me if I'm wrong) this also successfully prints :

```
1
2
3
4
```

## Example 3

```
i = 4 

def var_i3():

    if i >0:
    i += 1
    print(i)    
    
var_i3()

# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'i' referenced before assignment
```

#I don't understand why Python is okay with variable i as a list but not variable i as an integer

Comment: Please update your question with code formatting and also check the indentation of your code.

Comment: There's a nice explanation here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851906/python-3-unboundlocalerror-local-variable-referenced-before-assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't understand why Python is okay with variable i as a list but not variable i as an integer

It is unrelated to the type.

The line `i += 1` is treated by the interpreter as

i = i + 1

or, put differently,

i = "something"

because of this, the interpreter assumes that `i` in the context of this function is a local, not a global. However, it also appears in the line before, so, in terms of the interpreter, it is referencing it before it is defined.

If you explicitly make it `global`, it will work

```
i = 4

def var_i3():
    
    global i

    if i >0:
        i += 1
    print(i) 
    
var_i3()
5
```