# local variable referenced before assignment, Python

Tags: python-3.x, function, global-variables

I have a question regarding the error **local variable ... referenced before assignment** in Python3. Several cases of this error have been discussed in this forum (look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851906/python-3-unboundlocalerror-local-variable-referenced-before-assignment)); however they don't address my question. My problem at the moment is **not** how to resolve this issue, but to understand why there is such an issue.

Here is my code:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self,n):
        if n > 0:
            self.index = n
            self.check = v[0]
        else:
            self.index = n+5
            self.check = v[1]        
            v = [18,12]

v = [90,43]
g = Test(18)
```

The problem arises only because of that `v=[18,12]` assignment. If it is erased, there won't be any error. However, my issue is that 18 > 0, and as a result, the part of the code that comes after the `else` must be ignored. Thus, why is there such an error?

Comment: Can you fix the formatting of your code in the question?  Are the last 2 lines inside the class or not?

Comment: @RocketHazmat No they are **not** inside class. I will edit it now. Thanks

Comment: Also, what is `v = [90,43]` supposed to be?  Have you tried to put that before the `__init__` and then referencing `self.v` instead?

Comment: By putting ```v=[90,43]``` before ```__init__``` the problem is not resolved. However; as I said, at the moment I don't want to know how to resolve this issue, but want to know why there is an error at all.

Comment: There is an error because `__init__` doesn't know what `v` is.  That should probably be `self.v` instead.  If you set `v = [90,43]` inside the class (before `__init__`) then it can access that list as `self.v`.  If you don't want to do that, then you'll have to _pass_ `v` as a parameter to `__init__`.

Comment: `v` has local scope because of the `v = [18,12]` within your `__init__` method. It doesn't matter that you're in a different branch of your `if`/`else` statement. Simply having the assignment within your method means any other references to it will be referring to the local variable.

Comment: @RocketHazmat: nah, `__init__` does know. That's how global vars work in python.

Comment: @RocketHazmat If you erase ```v=[18,12]``` then there is no error. Therefore, eventhough ```v=[90,43]``` is defined outside the class, the class will recognize it.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I guess you're right, my bad.  I've just never coded this way.  If I were to do this, then `v` would be a parameter to `__init__` or it'd be referenced as `self.v`.

Answer (score 2):

> want to know why there is an error at all

The problem is that your assignment creates a *local variable* `v`, that shadows your global variable `v`. This happens at parse/load time. That's why python knows that you tried to use the local variable before giving it any value.