# Im getting the referenced before assignment error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a system that reads a file, moves it to a new file, and moves it back with a new variable at the end of each line.
It is saying that `linesRead` is referenced before assignment

```
import random
handVar = 0
handList = []
linesRead = 'test'
def dealCards(numPlayers, cardList):
    random.shuffle(cardList)
    for i in range(0, numPlayers):
        poppedCard1=cardList.pop()
        poppedCard2=cardList.pop()

        hand = (poppedCard1 + ', ' + poppedCard2)
        handList.append(hand)

        cardFile = open('players.txt', 'r')
        playerLines= cardFile.readlines()
        cardFile.close()
        for i in playerLines:
            for f in i:
                linesRead = linesRead + f
        print(linesRead)
        tempFile = open('tempFile.txt', 'w')
        tempFile.write(playerLines)
        tempFile.close
        tempFile = open('tempFile.txt', 'r')
        playerFile = open('players.txt', 'a')
         for i in tempFile:
            newLine= (i + ', ' + handList[handVar] + ', ' + handList[handVar+1])
            playerFile.write(newLine)
            handVar = handVar + 2
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UnboundLocalError on local variable when reassigned after first use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370357/unboundlocalerror-on-local-variable-when-reassigned-after-first-use)

Comment: Or [Python 3: UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10851906/4518341)

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error scopes of the variables.

You are defining the variable `linesRead` in the global scope (outside of the function). It is available inside the function as long as you do not try to reassign the variable. When you reassign, Python treats is as a local scope variable (the scope of the function), and since you are using it in the reassignment, it is not able to find the assignment of that var in local scope.

---

Let's look at the following examples:

```py
num = 42


def foo():
    print(num)
    
    
foo()
```

Output:

```
42
```

In this case `num` is a variable defined in the Global scope (aka. module scope). It is defined at the top level of the module and is available in the local scopes of functions.

But the things are different in the following example:

```py
num = 42


def foo():
    print(num)
    num = 12
    
    
foo()
```

Output:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'num' referenced before assignment
```

What happens in this case is Python making the `num` a variable of the local scope of the `foo` function. That is it has nothing to do with the `num` of the global scope. Since I'm trying to print it before I assign it a value, it gives me an error.

Things are different when I move the assignment above of the `print` function call:

```py
num = 42


def foo():
    num = 12
    print(num)
    
    
foo()
```

Output:

```
12
```

Same happens in this case, but since `num` is already assigned in the local scope by the time I'm calling the `print`, it won't error.

---

## Solution

One of the solutions is to include the var as a global in the function. Something like this

```py
def dealCards(numPlayers, cardList):
    global linesRead
```

it will make the var from global variable available at the local scope.

But in this case if you modify the var in the function, the one at the module level will be changed as well

```
num = 42


def foo():
    global num
    print(num)
    num = 12
    

foo()
print(num)
```

Output

```
42
12
```

---

Here is a fine, detailed read on Python scopes:
https://realpython.com/python-scope-legb-rule/