# How can I overwrite and existing list with an updated one?

Tags: python

I'm fairly new to programming and I'm trying to write a programm that will sort a list alphabetically. I would like to be able to change items from that list, but I have issues overwriting the original list with an updated one.
This what I have right now:

```
def add_items():
  add_list = input("Please enter your additional items separated by space: ")
  list_to_add = add_list.split(" ")
  new_list = finished_list + list_to_add
  updated_list = sorted(new_list)
  finished_list = updated_list[:]
```

I already tried to use in this case:

finished_list = updated_list[:]

but I always get this: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'finished_list' referenced before assignment

I hope some of you can help me! Btw, if you have other tips on something just tell me, I'd love to improve ^^

Comment: In the line `new_list = finished_list + list_to_add` where does `finished_list` come from? You don't seem to define it anywhere.

Comment: If finished_list is a global variable, you must declare it as such, otherwise a local variable by the same name is created

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python 3: UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851906/python-3-unboundlocalerror-local-variable-referenced-before-assignment)

Comment: You should always provide a [mre]. Anyway, by the looks of it, you have `finished_list` defined ***outside*** the function. The line `finished_list = ...` makes Python create another ***local*** variable with the same name. But when it get to the line `new_list = ...` that variable is not yet defined and hence you get the error...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to modify `finished_list`, you should pass it to your function as a parameter, and then call methods on it that will modify that original list, rather than assigning a different list to the same name:

```
def add_items(existing_items):
    add_list = input(
        "Please enter your additional items separated by space: "
    ).split()
    existing_items.extend(add_list)
    existing_items.sort()
```

and then call this with:

```
add_items(finished_list)
```

in order to add the items to `finished_list`.

The important distinction is in the way that the assignment operator works (I used `existing_items` as the parameter name above in order to make the following example easier to follow):

```
>>> finished_list = [1, 2, 3]
>>> existing_items = finished_list
>>> existing_items.extend([4, 5, 6])
>>> finished_list
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

In the above example, I `extend` `existing_items` with more items, and because the name `existing_items` refers to `finished_list`, the new items show up in that list.  What happens if instead I *assign* to `existing_items`?

```
>>> finished_list = [1, 2, 3]
>>> existing_items = finished_list
>>> existing_items = existing_items + [4, 5, 6]
>>> finished_list
[1, 2, 3]
>>> existing_items
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Because I did an assignment, I now have two different lists, and the original `finished_list` isn't affected.  (Note that if I do things like `existing_list.extend(...)` at this point, it still won't affect `finished_list`, because `existing_list` ceased to reference `finished_list` as soon as I did `existing_list = ...`.)  You get the same exact behavior when you do this type of assignment inside a function, *even if both of the variables are named `finished_list`*, because the body of a function has its own namespace and can have its own variables that "shadow" variables of the same name in the calling namespace.

One more example, using *slice assignment*, which is what you were attempting to do in your function at one point:

```
>>> finished_list = [1, 2, 3]
>>> existing_items = finished_list
>>> existing_items[:] = existing_items + [4, 5, 6]
>>> finished_list
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Slice assignment is an operation that modifies the elements of a existing list rather than assigning a new name to another list.  It looks very similar to a regular assignment, and in many cases might appear to behave identically, but it's very different, as the above examples show.