# Python lets you access a list, but not an int from an nested inner function?

Tags: python, function, scope, nested

```
def func1():
    nums = [1,3]
    j = 1
    def func2(k):
        nums.append(k)
        print(nums)
        j = j + k
        print(j)
    func2(5)
func1()
```

I understand that all arguments passed to outer function, `func1()`  , will be available to it's inner function `func2()`. When it comes to variables defined inside the outer function, like `nums` and `j` above, I can only access/modify the list and not the int. I get the output below:

```
    [1, 3, 5]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 10, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 9, in func1
  File "<input>", line 7, in func2
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'j' referenced before assignment
```

We can see the argument get appended to the `nums` in the output, but it throws an error when it gets to `j = j + k`. The same is true for sets, and dictionaries, they can be accessed from an inner function. How come I cannot access the int, but I can access the list, even though they are defined in the same scope?

Comment: The problem is the assignment, not the type.

Comment: Possible dupe:  [Short description of the scoping rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/291978/674039)

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica correct. Assignments are not allowed but the variable is still accessible.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that when you are assigning to `j` inside `func2`, you are creating a new local variable inside that function. Python then tries to reference that local variable (`j`) on the right-hand side of the assignment, and can't find any value assigned to it yet.

A possible solution is to use the `nonlocal` keyword on `j` like this:

```py
def func1():
    nums = [1,3]
    j = 1
    def func2(k):
        nonlocal j
        nums.append(k)
        print(nums)
        j = j + k
        print(j)
    func2(5)
func1()
```

Which produces

```
[1, 3, 5]
6
```

This post is related an might give you some more clarity: [Python 3: UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851906/python-3-unboundlocalerror-local-variable-referenced-before-assignment)

Also some more information from the Python docs: https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value

Answer (score -2):

```
def func2(j, k)
```

And call it with:

```
func2(j, 5)
```

Worked when I tested it like this.