# Scope error when returning function from function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, functional-programming, closures

I am having issues with using function generators in python, i.e. returning functions from a function, where some of the inputs are defined via the outer function's arguments, yielding a function with lower arity. I have used this method before in other cases without issue but I have run into an error in this case and haven't been able to understand the reason. I have the following function that produces a function:

```
def func1(s: set, f: Callable) -> Callable:
    def func2(x: int) -> dict:
        while x:
            s = s - {x}
            x = f(x)
        return s
    return func2

f2 = func1({1,2,3,4}, lambda x: x-1)
```

If I try `f2(3)`, I get the error `"local variable 's' referenced before assignment"` related to the `s = s - {x}` statement. I don't understand why `s` is not part of the scope since I assumed it was fixed when `func1` was called to create `f2`.

I was able to fix this issue by instead using this method: I combine all the arguments into one function, say `func3` and use the `functools.partial` operation, which behaves as expected:

```
from functools import partial
def func3(x: int, s: set, f: Callable) -> dict:
    while x:
        s = s - {x}
        x = f(x)
    return s

f2 = partial(func3, s={1,2,3,4}, f=lambda x: x-1)
```

When I call `f2(3)` I get `{4}` as expected.

My understanding is that both of these approaches should yield the same result; however, I am apparently missing something about how variable scope operates in the first case. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python 3: UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851906/python-3-unboundlocalerror-local-variable-referenced-before-assignment)

Comment: What output do you expect for `print(f2(2), f2(3), f2(2))`?

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your first piece of code is that `s` is a local variable inside `func2`.  It has no connection to the variable `s` that you've defined inside `func1`.  Remember that any variable that is assigned to within a function is local, unless you declare it otherwise.

The fix is to add `nonlocal s` to your definition of `func2`.  Python will then realize that the `s` referred to inside `func2` is the same as the `s` inside `func1`.

@KellyBundy points out that this may still not give you exactly what you want.  If you simply make `s` nonlocal, you are effectively saying that these two variables point point to the same set.  Any changes made to `s` are "permanent".  The second time `f2` is called, the value of `s` will be whatever it was at the end of the first time `f2` is called.  It is uncertain if this is what is intended.

If you want `s` to be reset each time `f2` is called, you need to keep the two `s`s separate.  The simplest way would be to start off `func2` with `s0 = s`, and then just use `s0` within `func2.  Since` s`is never modified within`func2`, it refers to the outer variable.  And you have a different variable` s0`within`func2` that can be modified as you wish.

Comment: With `nonlocal` it's not equivalent to their`partial` version, though. Not clear what they really want.

Comment: @KellyBundy.  Not sure what you mean.  Both return the same answer.  Both close over the variable `s`, but use different syntax to do so.  I'm sure internally, they're very different.

Comment: Given that they tagged `functional-programming`, whose description even says "avoiding side effects", I'm inclined to suspect this isn't what they desire.

Comment: Try `print(f2(2), f2(3), f2(2))` with their `partial` solution and with the solution fixed like you propose.

Comment: The specific question in the text was "I don't understand why `s` isn't in scope".  I explained it to them and showed them how to fix it.

Comment: Your explanation is good. Your proposed fix is doubtful.

Comment: Put differently: I suspect a proper fix would be to not shadow the outer variable, by calling the outer variable let's say `s0` and starting the inner function with `s = s0`.

Comment: I see what you're saying.  It's unclear what OP expects the scope of `s` is supposed to be.  In one case, `s` is always `{1, 2, 3, 4}` at the start of the inner function.  In the latter, it's whatever value `s` had at the last time it was called.  Will add your comments.