# Why I can change list from Local?

Tags: python-3.x

In this example we don't see a_int, so this code don't be work

```py
a_int=123

def tmp():
  a_int+=2
```

but why this example work?

```py
a_list=[1,2,3]
def tmp():
  a_list.append(4)
```

As I understood in example 2, a_list is a link, and therefore we have access to it?
I'm not sure if my guesses are correct, can you please explain this to me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python 3: UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851906/python-3-unboundlocalerror-local-variable-referenced-before-assignment)

Comment: @Nick: How does that explain `a_list`?

Comment: @ScottHunter you're not assigning to `a_list`, you are modifying the object it points to...

Comment: @ScottHunter if you change the second `tmp` to `a_list = a_list + [4]` (effectively the same thing) you get the unBoundLocalError because you are assigning a new value to `a_list`

Comment: @Nick: Yes, but my point was that your "duplicate" answer doesn't address those points, and I would argue warrants its own answer (which you have pretty much laid out in comments).

Comment: @ScottHunter sorry, it was late and I didn't get your point. You're right, that answer and none of the others it links to mention lists (or dicts for that matter) and how their behaviour is different.