# python function global and local scope confusion

Tags: python, function, global-variables, local-variables

I have a code in which I declare a variable globally. Then inside a function, when I try to use it, it gives an error `Unbound variable is not declared`
My code:

```
count_url =1

def foo():
   ...
           ttk.Label(canvas1, text=f'{varSongTitle}...Done! {count_url}/{str(var_len)}').pack(padx=3,pady=3)
        root.update()
        count_url = count_url + 1
```

When I read from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851906/python-3-unboundlocalerror-local-variable-referenced-before-assignment) that for bypassing this issue: The issue as I guess was that inside function my globally declared variable was becoming local, I guess because after printing it out I was assigning it to `count_url =+` That's why I needed to also decalre it globally inside function as below:

```
count_url =1

def foo():
   global count_url
   ...
           ttk.Label(canvas1, text=f'{varSongTitle}...Done! {count_url}/{str(var_len)}').pack(padx=3,pady=3)
        root.update()
        count_url = count_url + 1
```

Now code works perfectly! But I have pair of questions `How? Why?`. Why it does not behave similarly if I assign `global` in global scope like

```
global count_url
count_url=1

def foo():
...
```

And also How can this be possible, that due to assigning inside the function a value to my global variable, why it becomes local?
ANSWER: https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value

> This is because when you make an assignment to a variable in a scope, that variable becomes local to that scope and shadows any similarly named variable in the outer scope. Since the last statement in foo assigns a new value to x, the compiler recognizes it as a local variable. Consequently when the earlier print(x) attempts to print the uninitialized local variable and an error results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default behavior of Python is to create a new variable in the function scope without checking the global scope for a similarly named variable.

The global declaration inside the function tells Python that you want to use the variable declared in the outer scope instead of creating a new one.

Adding a reference to the official Python documentation, from a comment: https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value

Comment: ` use the variable declared in the outer scope` I thought declaring global inside function is for using it in outer scope. But, now your words describe it as, python looks for that variable in outer scope

Comment: Yes, you understood what I said correctly.

Comment: Thanks, I will also look for it in documentations

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value